# Java - Deserialization Annotations with fasterXML and Jackson

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, fasterxml

Here's a simple example of **working code** to deserialize a string list using fasterXML/Jackson in the constructor:

```
private List<String> xyz;

@JsonCreator
public FooBar(@JsonProperty("blargs") List<String> xyz)
{
    this.xyz = xyz
}
```

So, the above code works fine, and it's my understanding of how to use Jackson to deserialize a json string like such: `{"blargs":["one","two","three"]}`

So, here's my question:

My input json now looks like such:

```
{"blargs":[
    {"fooId":888,"barVal":"tacos"},
    {"fooId":222,"barVal":"hamburgers"},
    {"fooId":444,"barVal":"underpants"}
  ]
}
```

...but I can't figure out how to annotate the constructor to deserialize the incoming json into my map where fooId and barVal become the key/value pairs.

Here's what I'm working with so far

```
private Map<Integer, String> xyz;

@JsonCreator
public FooBar(@JsonProperty("blargs") ????? Map<Integer, String> xyz)
{
    this.xyz = xyz
}
```

note: I am calling the constructors shown above as such:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
FooBar fooBar = mapper.readValue(jsonValue, FooBar.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom deserializer:

```
public static class XyzDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<Integer, String>> {

    @Override
    public Map<Integer, String> deserialize(JsonParser p,
                                            DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode rootNode = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        rootNode.forEach(n -> map.put(
                n.get("fooId").intValue(),
                n.get("barVal").asText()
        ));
        return map;
    }
}
```

And use it in this way:

```
@JsonCreator
public FooBar(
        @JsonProperty("blargs")
        @JsonDeserialize(using = XyzDeserializer.class) Map<Integer, String> xyz) {
    this.xyz = xyz;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you!  btw, I haven't found any super great documentation (tutorial and reference) for fasterxml/jackson, do you have any 'goto' places that are easy to understand?

Comment: @russellelbert You can start with this [get started guide](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind#use-it). 
Here is [a useful info about annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations#usage-general)

Answer (score 1):

You need a class for the data

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\"blargs\":[\n"
                + "    {\"fooId\":888,\"barVal\":\"tacos\"},\n"
                + "    {\"fooId\":222,\"barVal\":\"hamburgers\"},\n"
                + "    {\"fooId\":444,\"barVal\":\"underpants\"}\n"
                + "  ]\n"
                + "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        FooBar fooBar = mapper.readValue(json, FooBar.class);
    }

    public static class FooBar {

        private List<MyObject> xyz;

        @JsonCreator
        public FooBar(@JsonProperty("blargs") List<MyObject> xyz) {
            this.xyz = xyz;
            System.out.println(this.xyz);
        }

    }

    public static class MyObject {

        private int fooId;
        private String barVal;

        public int getFooId() {
            return fooId;
        }

        public void setFooId(int fooId) {
            this.fooId = fooId;
        }

        public String getBarVal() {
            return barVal;
        }

        public void setBarVal(String barVal) {
            this.barVal = barVal;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyObject{" + "fooId=" + fooId + ", barVal=" + barVal + '}';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but used the 'extends JsonDeserializer' paradigm for my implementation - I may come back to this later... thank you!